# how to add system.diagnostics.process to bot framework

Tags: c#, azure, vbscript, process, botframework

I am new for microsoft botframework, I have to redirect to google page and search for specific user input keyword. I used some vbscript for this google process and calling the file from c# process code like this.

```
public virtual async Task message2(IDialogContext context,IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> argument)
    {
          ProcessStartInfo ps = new ProcessStartInfo();
            ps.FileName = "cscript.exe";
            ps.Arguments = string.Format("\"{0}\" \"{1}\" , @"D:\democtrl.vbs","" );
            var process = Process.Start(ps);
            process.WaitForExit();
            process.Close();
            await context.PostAsync("Submitted Successfully");
            context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);
```

}`

I am running the vbscript file from local machine. when I do it in emulator I can able to run the file. But after publishing to azure it was not working.. do anyone suggest me or help me with any documents to do this.

Comment: You can just show a button that will open Google with the search query. Why would you use vbs script for that?

Comment: Ya using button I can open the url but i have to enter user input in the google search box and also click on search button, How do i achieve that using c#?

Comment: Just point the user to https://www.google.com.ar/search?q=my+search+statement where 'my+search+statement' is the user input

Comment: thanks @EzequielJadib but this is one example, my intension is to fill the text box of other pages to where I cant find these kind of url links  (google.com.ar/search?q=my+search+statement). I need to inject js into the webpage to fill the textbox and also for click events thats why I used vbscripts

Answer (score 0):

> Ya using button I can open the url but i have to enter user input in the google search box and also click on search button, How do i achieve that using c#?

Based on my understanding for your question, you want to use user's input for google search.

If so, to invoke google search in your `Bot`, a simple way is to configure google application and customize your search API. On `Bot` side, we can send `Http` request and get response for example like this:

```
private async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> argument)
{
    var activity = await argument;
    if (activity.Text != "")
    {
        var input = activity.Text;
        string url = "http://example.com/search?q={input}"
        var request = WebRequest.Create("url");
        var response = await request.GetResponseAsync();
        //TODO:
    }
    context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);
}
```

For the part of google search api, you may refer to [Using REST to Invoke the API](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/using_rest).

If I have any misunderstanding, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: thanks @grace feng, google search is one example but I have another page where I have to fill all the input field and check some boxes.. So thats why I used vbscripts for that actions and trying to call from bot framework

Comment: hi @grace feng, but the above code is also not working it is showing error as sorry my bot code has issues

Comment: @SUNITHA, what did you do in your script? Can the work be moved into your bot application? If your script used some system level's resources/ dll, it may not work on Azure web app. By the way, which service of azure did you use to deploy your bot application? What is the error message in above code?

Comment: why vbscript used is, I have a web app form where I have fill all the fields and click submit button.  and I am using app service of free trial in azure web app and I am getting server error

Comment: @SUNITHA, `Bot Framework` is based on web api, so what your requirement in web form can also be implemented in web api. Besides, azure web app has restrictions and it's difficult for us to troubleshoot your vbscript on Azure web Apps without error messages. My suggestion is to implement your requirement in bot app or you can build up a standalone web app to implement the web form functionality and export the api for your bot application.